# how to associate key to each individual array and make them key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have `array` like this

`[["apple","banana"],["monkey"]];`

how can i `associate key`   to them    like,

```
[{"fruit":["apple","banana"],"wild":["monkey"]}]
```

is this possible?

i'm trying something like this

```
var arr = [["apple","banana"],["monkey"]];
var newArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    newArray["fruit"] = arr[i] //further code i don't know
}
```

help me th

Comment: Your examples say that you want to convert an array containing two entries, each of which is an array, into an array containing **one** entry: An object with two properties, the values of which are the original two array entries. Is that really correct? It seems an odd thing to do.

Comment: How do you know banana and apple are fruits and monkey is wild? What is the way the code will decide this?

Answer (score 1):

While you **can** do that, like this:

```js
var array = [["apple","banana"],["monkey"]];
var update = [
  {fruit: array[0], wild: array[1]}
];
console.log(update);
```

...frankly it seems unlikely that's really want you want.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply you can assign a new name simply

```
var array = [["apple","banana"],["monkey"]];
var names = ["fruits", "wild"]
var modified = [{names[0]: array[0], names[1]: array[1]}];
```

If you have a lot of values just use a `for` loop to iterate and assign value to it.